# PHPMailer won't send html message with media queries

Tags: php

I am using PHPmailer to send emails.

```
php 7.4
phpmailer 5.2
thunderbird - emailclient 78
```

[tiny](https://www.tiny.cloud/) for email body

**UPDATE 1** both tiny and thunderbird for security reasons removes `@media`

I have a responsive e-mails with media queries. E-mails come from MySql database. I can send e-mails but after sending phpmailer romemoves media queries. I tested on 2 SMTP mail servers - the same result.

My code looks like this.

**send_emai.php**

```
    $body_id = $_POST['body_id'];

    $res2 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from news_body where id='$body_id'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2);
    $mail_body = $row['description'];

    smtp_mailer($email,$mail_subject,$mail_body);

function smtp_mailer($to,$subject,$msg) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SetFrom("syrius@xxxx");
    $mail->Host             =   "xxxx";
    $mail->Port             =   465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure       =   "ssl";
    $mail->SMTPAuth         =   true;
    $mail->Username         =   "xxxx";
    $mail->Password         =   'xxxx';

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $msg;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPOptions=array('ssl'=>array(
        'verify_peer'=>false,
        'verify_peer_name'=>false,
        'allow_self_signed'=>false
    ));
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        //echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        //echo 'Sent';
    }
}
```

**email before sending**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {....
```

**after sending**
there is nothing, code has been removed

Comment: What happens instead? "There is nothing" sounds strange. Also, your query to gather the news body is widely open for SQL injection

Comment: @Nico Haase I know :) the code is for testing... at the end it will be PDO.

Comment: You have a bias in your question, you assume this has to do with PHPMailer. You disregard your own mailserver, the receiving mailserver and the receiving mailclient. Especially the last could be the culprit.

Comment: @Nico Haase In the mail client in preview after sending - there is no `@media ....`

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Have you checked whether the mail is really sent with that body?

Comment: @KIKO Software you're right, it's a Thunderbird client, if you want, then write a reply and I will accept it.

Comment: @Mantykora7: Added the answer.

Comment: It's best to omit your media queries and use inline CSS for best compatibility with most mail clients. And yes, they are removing/transforming your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bias in your question, you assume this has to do with PHPMailer. You disregard your own mailserver, the receiving mailserver and the receiving mailclient. Especially the last could be the culprit.

For instance if you are [using Thunderbird](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/8621-thunderbird-and-responsive-emails-media-queries).

But other email clients could change the content of emails as well. This is usually done for security reasons.